# I want to Hide side bar using Jquery for specific users in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to hide and show sidebar for specific user levels using `jquery` in `CodeIgniter`. **User id** should retrieve from the database directly in view

```
<?php if(in_array('updateOrder', $user_permission) || in_array('viewOrder', $user_permission) || in_array('deleteOrder', $user_permission)): ?>

<li id="manageOrdersNav">
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('orders/index')?>">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Manage Orders
  </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Now, What is the issue with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll get a much better response if you give us some critical information including what you've tried so far and what specifically is going wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some good advice.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you have set in permission variable. but after loading jquery you can use it

```
<?php if ( $user_permission == 'denied' ){ ?>
<script> $('#manageOrdersNav').hide(); </script>
<?php } ?>
```

or 
at top of you page

```
<?php if ( $user_permission == 'denied' ){ ?>
<script> var manageOrdersNav = true </script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script> var manageOrdersNav = false </script>
<?php } ?>
```

at bottom of you page

```
<script>
if (manageOrdersNav = true){ 
$('#manageOrdersNav').hide();
}
</script>
```

you can do.

but the better way of doing it is with php as you have done